# Matlab - Matrix of points on a circle edge

Tags: image, matlab

How can I find the matrix of points that make up the edge of a circle of any radius in Matlab? If I plot these points, I should get something close to a circle (though a smooth circle is made up of infinite number of points).

Comment: Did you try to Google for that? Here's one of the first search results: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15I2I/

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will try that, I need the matrix of all points on the edge for a bigger Matlab problem I need to solve.

Comment: This is pretty basic MATLAB. I suggest you get yourself familiar with MATLAB basics before proceeding to take on more advanced problems. If you run into a specific problem, post a question. In any case, good luck and welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
radius = 5;                                    %desired radius
numPoints = 1000;                              %Number of points in your circle
angles = linspace(0,2*pi,numPoints)';          %Angles evenly spread around the circle, from 0 to 2*pi radians
xyCircle = radius*[cos(angles) sin(angles)];   %This is the matrix you probably want

plot(xyCircle(:,1), xyCircle(:,2),'.'); %Quick plot to check the result
axis equal;
```